# Sort nested arrays in array of object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I don't know why, but sorting is one of the things by programming that confuses me every time...

I want to sort the array members on the first level so, that all members with the properties **licence: "truck" and active: true** are at first in the list. Then the next members should be all members with **licence: "car" and active: true**

underscore.js is avaiable...

```
[
        {
            name: 'Denes',
            properties: [
                {
                    licence: "car",
                    active: true
                },
                {
                    licence: "truck",
                    active: false
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Patrick',
            properties: [
                {
                    licence: "car",
                    active: false
                },
                {
                    licence: "truck",
                    active: true
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Marc',
            properties: [
                {
                    licence: "car",
                    active: false
                },
                {
                    licence: "truck",
                    active: false
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Expected result:

```
[

        {
            name: 'Patrick',
            properties: [
                {
                    licence: "car",
                    active: false
                },
                {
                    licence: "truck",
                    active: true
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Denes',
            properties: [
                {
                    licence: "car",
                    active: true
                },
                {
                    licence: "truck",
                    active: false
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Marc',
            properties: [
                {
                    licence: "car",
                    active: false
                },
                {
                    licence: "truck",
                    active: false
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: please add the result of the sorting.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? It's just a matter of using `Array#sort` and comparing the objects according to your criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function comparator(){
    return function(a, b){
        return weightage(b)- weightage(a);
    }
};

function weightage(obj){
    var maxWeight = -1;
    for (var i in obj.properties){
        if(obj.properties[i].licence == 'truck' && obj.properties[i].active) {
            maxWeight = 1;
            return maxWeight;
        } else if (obj.properties[i].licence == 'car' && obj.properties[i].active) {
            maxWeight = 0;
        }
    }
    return maxWeight;
};
```

assuming your array is named: `arr` call `arr.sort(comparator())` .
Hope this solves your query.. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 1):

A compound key for this sort would be the sum of active properties with respect to the sort order + the name, in case there are many people with equal properties. That gives:

```
sortOrder = {'truck':1 , 'car': 2}

result = _.sortBy(data, item => [
    _(item.properties)
        .filter(prop => prop.active)
        .map(prop => sortOrder[prop.licence])
        .sum()
    ,
    item.name]
).reverse();
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and a function for a sort priority would help.

```js
var arr = [{ name: 'Denes', properties: [{ licence: "car", active: true }, { licence: "truck", active: false }, ] }, { name: 'Patrick', properties: [{ licence: "car", active: false }, { licence: "truck", active: true }, ] }, { name: 'Marc', properties: [{ licence: "car", active: false }, { licence: "truck", active: false }, ] }];

arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    function max(r, a) {
        return Math.max(r, ({ truck: 2, car: 1 }[a.licence] || 0) + ({ true: 8, false: 4 }[a.active] || 0));
    }
    return b.properties.reduce(max, 0) - a.properties.reduce(max, 0);
})

console.log(arr);
```